# How to find out my ISP

Tags: php, email, ini

In ini.php I'm changing `SMTP = localhost` to my isp to send email from localhost. However I don't know how to find the isp.

Not sure if this is relevant.. I use Comcast internet and my email is on either aol or yahoo.

Comment: You just told us your ISP is Comcast. They should tell you what smtp server to use if they're also providing you with email services.

Comment: Oh I see! but in what format do I write it in ini.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick search I found [this](http://customer.comcast.com/%28X%281%29S%28ren15g45mxjaps55q4bcue55%29%29/Pages/FAQViewer.aspx?Guid=b454828c-37a6-459a-9191-2a1b0f2bb20e&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

It says smtp.comcast.net .

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet, if you are going to try to send mail through aol or yahoo, is to use Pear::mail.

Once you install it, it makes sending mail much simpler for complicated setups.

I've used it when I needed to send mail through an authenticated mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are going to host your website on a hosted server somewhere, then you will have to find the SMTP server your hosting company is providing. Your ISP server won't work from another hosted location other than your home connection.